# Recursively add to a list for a given N number of times

Tags: haskell

i'm trying to create a function where given a number and a list, you add the given number to the list and decrement that number.  You do this until the number hits 0 and return the list.

IE "incList 5 []" should return [5,4,3,2,1]

This is the code I have so far

```
incList :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
incList 0 xs = []
incList g [] = []
incList g (x:xs) = g:x ++ incList (g-1) (xs)
```

Im using 'a' since i want the list to consist of anything later on.

Im currently getting this error:

```
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’ with actual type ‘a’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for incList :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
      at incList.hs:1:12
Relevant bindings include
  xs :: [a] (bound at incList.hs:4:14)
  x :: a (bound at incList.hs:4:12)
  incList :: Int -> [a] -> [a] (bound at incList.hs:2:1)
In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘x’
In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘x ++ incList (g - 1) (xs)’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you want to pre-pend a list with numeric values counting down from some starting value.  There are a couple type and logic errors in your first try:

```
incList :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
```

First off, you are saying your starting value is an `Int` but your list contains any value (via the `a` type variable).  You can't have a list of mixed types `Int` and `a` so you must unify these somehow.

To be clear, you said "Im using 'a' since i want the list to consist of anything later on.".  But that isn't a valid option - the list must only consist of one type and you seem to have decided to use numbers.

Moving on, we get to your custom recursive function.  Making your own is fine, just know that this can be handled with built in functions or syntactic sugar.

```
incList 0 xs = []
incList g [] = []
```

Your first base-case is good but the second one, not so much.  You specifically said `incList 5 []` should not be `[]` but `[5,4,3,2,1]` so how about you drop the second case above.

```
incList g (x:xs) = g:x ++ incList (g-1) (xs)
```

And here, why are you de-constructing the original list (`x:xs`).  I thought you wanted to pre-pend values, not to take values off and mix the new values with the old.

Also, the expression `g:x ++` makes no sense.  `x` is not a list so neither is `g : x` and thus they don't make a valid argument for `(++) :: Int -> Int -> Int`, you probably were going for `g : x : incList ...`.

With these changes we arrive at:

```
incList :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
incList 0 xs = xs
incList g xs = g : incList (g-1) xs
```

This is almost the same as:

```
incList g xs = [g,g-1..1] ++ xs
```

Which is a little cleaner to read.

Comment: I arrived at incList :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] as my base scenario before posting the question.  however im trying to apply the same idea to say populating an empty list of strings 10 times with the word "yep for example.

Comment: That comment did not suffice to clarify your question.

Comment: perhaps im thinking about this problem too much in imperative terms since im new at this language but to clarify.. I would like to create a list and fill it with things such as Strings (so list of strings) etc. but I want to pass in a number (N) to the function where it adds to that list some string N amount of times into the list and then give me the list of strings

Comment: Where do the new strings come from? Could you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

The `++` operator is the list concatenation operator. Its type is `[a] -> [a] -> [a]`. That means that both its inputs are lists. As you can see from the error, you are passing `x` as the first input to `++` and the type of `x` is simply `a`.

Try replacing this use of `++` with `:`, for example:

```
incList g (x:xs) = g : x : incList (g-1) (xs)
```

The type of `:` is `a -> [a] -> [a]`, which should work here. There may be other issues going on, I haven't checked.